# IList for model binding in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC4 application I have an admin part. In this admin view I can see all the not (yet) accepted users who have registered. This view is also an editor for the ienumerable. To have an editor for an IEnumerable, I have added IList and for-loop like this in my view:

```
@model IList<PlusPlatform.Models.UserProfile>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActivated)
            </th>
        </tr>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].DepartmentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].IsActivated)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

But now the problem is I can't use the Html.DisplayNameFor and the Html.LabelFor. What can I do to display the labels correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really care about the `IList<T>`, you can change your model to `IEnumerable<T>`. [DisplayNameFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833697%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method has an overload for `IEnumerable`, that means you will be able to do this:

```
@model IEnumerable<PlusPlatform.Models.UserProfile>
...
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
</th>
```

`LabelFor` doesn't have this overload, because `label` should be used for a specific element, such as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => Model[i].UserName)
```

**EDIT:**

If you wan to post that data to controller, better create an `EditorTemplate`, name it `UserProfile`:

```
@model PlusPlatform.Models.UserProfile
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.DepartmentId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.IsActivated)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then in the View get rid of the loop:

```
@model IEnumerable<PlusPlatform.Models.UserProfile>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
            </th>
            ...
        </tr>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </table>
 }
```

Comment: I care about the IList, because when I use the `IEnumerable<T>` the Model will be null when submitting the form to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label@Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.First().UserName)</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.First().FirstName)</label>
            </th>
            <th>
               <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.First().LastName)</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.First().DepartmentId)</label>
            </th>
            <th>
               <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.First().IsActivated)</label>
            </th>
        </tr>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].DepartmentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].IsActivated)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I know this works correctly, but isn't this a bad practice? Say I change the model's display name, then the labels won't update.

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP clearly wants to take advantage from the data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use EditorFor in that way, then why not DisplayFor?
Try this

```
  @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => Model[0].FirstName)
```